# Robot localization using sensor fusion (How to model the Extended Kalman Filter)?

Tags: kalman-filter, cameras, odometry, sensor-fusion

I am new to the robotics field and sensor fusion as well.

I am trying to localize my robot using the data from my camera and the odometery through extended Kalman filter.

I have the data offline, I synchronized them. However I have a trouble with constructing the $F, H$ matrices.

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

This is the advice I gave to BOB but will be useful for you as well.

I recommend you to run an ekf slam tutorial code and analyse it. There is a perfect one for you: robots.ox.ac.uk/~SSS06/Website/index.html It is the simplest EKF SLAM but quite well coded and easy to read if you know matlab. I am sure the most of your implementational questions will be easily answered by looking at this code.

Practical 1 & 2 in the above link contains 90% of the things you need for implementing mono ekf slam or 2d ekf slam.

Another material for theoretical aspect on slam is [here](http://www.isir.upmc.fr/UserFiles/File/clady_homepage/M2/C4BMobileRobots.pdf)